# h_errno always print "unknown host"

Tags: c, unix, network-programming

I was trying to call `gethostbyname()` in my program. It worked well. I can get aliases and address list. But when I want to call `herror()` to print out `h_errno`, it always says `"Unknown Host"`.

Can anyone explain to me why did `h_errno` is 1, meaning `"Unknown Host"`, while I can still get aliases and address list by calling `gethostbyname()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The value of h_errno is only meaningful if the gethostby* function failed. Don't look at it otherwise.

Comment: Just want to add that the same goes for `errno`, never look at it unless the function you called returns with an error.